# Installing libgazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.so

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tried

> sudo apt install ros-noetic-gazebo*

> sudo apt install ros-noetic-moveit*

I assume libgazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.so would live in /opt/ros/noetic/lib.
I need this lib to publish a world scene (basically a robot workcell) from gazebo for moveit to use in collision detection/path planning for a robot within a workcell.

Does anyone know where the library is located/how it is installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391444/installing-libgazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.so/) by [JobvanDieten](https://answers.ros.org/users/90177/jobvandieten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-22**:
Try to install:

`sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-noetic-gazebo-ros-control`

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-22**:
Check this PR that describes the missing .so file:
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@osilva Thanks for the PR link. I have submitted a similar [PR](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/1334) for the noetic branch.

---

Originally posted by [JobvanDieten](https://answers.ros.org/users/90177/jobvandieten/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0